# Minimal circle containing set of points

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose that there are $n$ points in the plane $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$, and $C$ is the minimal circle (the circle with the minimal radius) that contains all of them. If there is another point $p$ outside of $C$, then how can one prove that $p$ is lying on the minimal circle containing $x_1, \dots , x_n, p$? It looks so intuitive, but I can't find a way to prove it... Any help?

Comment: Assume $p$ is strictly inside the new minimal circle. Try constructing (or proving the existence of) a circle smaller than this new minimal circle that still contains $p$.

Comment: Yeah @flawr, but how? If the center was fixed I could just make the radius smaller, but in this case I don't know whether it would left some other point otside...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $D$ be the disk bounded by the radius minimizing circle $\partial D = C\{{x_1, \dots, x_n\}}$.  Two outcomes, $p \in D$ or $p \notin D$.

If $p \notin C\{x_1, \dots, x_n, p\}$ then $p$ is inside the disk $D$ bounded by $C\{{x_1, \dots, x_n\}}$.  But we assumed $p \notin D$.

---

This is an instance of the [problem of Appolonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius#Ten_combinations_of_points.2C_circles.2C_and_lines).  By induction, we are looking for the smallest circle $C_1 = C\{x_1, \dots, x_n, p\}$ which contains $p$ and $C_0 = C\{{x_1, \dots, x_n\}}$.

[image]

If $p$ is not inside $C_0$, then $C_1$ should be tangent $C_0$ and go through $p$.  For this case of the Appolonius problem, you actually need **two** points to specify a unique circle.

In other words, there are infinitely circles $C_1$ passing through $p$ and tangent to $C_0$.  One of these has the smallest radius.

---

The above is not quite true... instead of $C_1$ being tangent to $C_0$ and $p$, just $C_1$ goes through $p$ and its tangent to the convex hull, $\overline{\{x_1, \dots, x_n \}}$.

> **Lemma** <del>The diameter of the minimal circle is the same as the diameter of the convex hull</del>
>   The minimizing circle cuts through at least three points in the set. Generically, exactly 3.

The circle needs surround all the points so the diameter is at least that of the convex hull, but it can be bigger.  If the min circle didn't go through any points, we could shrink the radius so it passes through at least one.  In fact, since 3 points determine a circle, we can shrink the radius until  it passes through at least 3.  Generically, there shouldn't be a fourth point exactly on the circle.

So we can run through all $\binom{n}{3}$ triples of points, verify the circumcircle contains all the other points, and find the one with the smallest radius.  For the induction, we adjoin $p$ and iterate through the $\binom{n+1}{3}$ points.

---

I found graphic in a graduate Computer Science course, on the "[Minimal Enclosing Circle](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs507/projects/1998/jacob/problem.html)" problem.  Wikipedia calls this the "[Smallest Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)" and attributes it to Mathematician [James Joseph Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joseph_Sylvester).  This question was also asked on the StackOverflow programming site:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901535/smallest-circle-which-covers-given-points-on-2d-plane
- [Is this a wrong solution to the smallest enclosing circle problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208230/is-this-a-wrong-solution-to-the-smallest-enclosing-circle-problem)

It was a computer science homework for sophomores at Princeton ([Cos 226](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring09/cos226/assignments/circle.html))
Literature points to a fast solution by Emo Welzl.  The paper is called **[Smallest Enclosing Disks (Balls and Ellipsoids)](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/PublFiles/SmallEnclDisk_LNCS555_91.pdf)**

[image]

---

> **Proposition** the radius minimizing circle is unique

For contradiction, if we have two circles $C, C'$ which  contain all $n$ points, these points must lie in the intersection of the two circles $C \cap C'$.  The intersection of these two circles is a [lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(mathematics))  shape with diameter smaller than that of $C$ or $C'$.

This diameter determines a circle still containing all $n$ points, but with diameter smaller than that of $C$ or $C'$.

Comment: How do you know that the circle $C_1$ must contain the entire circle $C_0$? It has to contain the points $x_1, \dots, x_n, p$ and I guess it could cut some of the $C_0$'s interior... Can you explain?

Comment: @brick You are correct, e.g. take $\{ 0, 1 \} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and adjoin the point $p = i$ in the complex plane.  The minimal circles cut each other.  We can still do induction where $C_1$ must surround $p$ and the convex hull of $x_1, \dots, x_n$.

Comment: Yeah, I agree about the convex hull, but it makes the things more complicated. Don't understand how to do the induction using it instead of the circle...

Comment: @brick the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) is a more delicate object than a circle, which is why I tried to do without it.  My original two-line proof still works.  The rest of the discussion is trying to construct the new minimizing circle $C_1$.

Comment: Yeah I think I got the idea of your original proof. However I think it might not work if the minimal circle is not unique (I mean if we have $2$ such circles with minimal diameter containing all of the points, but their centers are different). This is the main thing which bothers me. I guess it should be unique, but I can't see how. If this is the case everything is OK.

Comment: @brick it's unique because otherwise you can build a circle containing all the points, smaller than your original two "minimum" circles.

Comment: Oh, finally I got it completely. Thank you very much!

Comment: "If $p\not\in C\{x_1,…,x_n,p\}$ then $p$ is inside the disk $D$ bounded by $C\{x_1,…,x_n\}.$" how do you know $C\{x_1,…,x_n\}.$ is not a completely different circle from $C\{x_1,…,x_n,p\}.$?

Comment: Also the lemma is false, it might only go through two points.  Consider three collinear points.

Answer (score 1):

It is so because these are *circles*. The center and radius of C is known. Draw a perpendicular from outside point p onto circle $C$ having a diameter $\phi_C$ . Let this outside distance along normal be $d$.

The new minimal circle diameter containing point $p$ and $C$ is $ \phi_C + d $ because line length $d$ is added along diameter of C.

Answer (score 0):

For any set of different points $x$, the circular hull (the minimal circle containing all points) of $x$ is equal to the circular hull of a subset of $x$, that subset having exactly $2$ or $3$ points.  There may be multiple subsets, but there is at least $1$.

There is then exactly $1$ point $c$ that is equidistant $r$ from those $3$ points (or the midpoint of $2$ points).  This $c$ is the center of the circular hull.

Every other point has a distance to $c$ which is less than or equal to $r$.  The question assumes that the distance of $p$ to $c$ is greater than $r$.

$x \cup \{p\}$ also has a subset of $2$ or $3$ points that determines its circular hull.

The claim is that every such subset of points which has the same circular hull as $x \cup \{p\}$ must contain $p$.

Consider a $y$ such that : $y \subseteq x$, $|y| = 3$ or $|y| = 2$, $p \not \in y$

If that $y$ formed a circular hull of $x \cup \{p\}$ then it also forms a circular hull of $x$.  But in the former case, the distance of $p$ to the center is less than the radius of the circular hull and in the latter case it contradicts the assumption of that $p$ is outside of the circular hull of $x$.

So all such $y$ cannot be a circular hull of $x \cup \{p\}$ so all subsets of points determining the circular hull of $x \cup \{p\}$ must contain $p$.

Comment: I'm not sure that the set, which determines the circular must have exactly $3$ elements (if the points lie on a single line you can take the ends of the segment, which contains all of the points, then these 2 points are enough to determine the circle). Also I think this proof works only if the circular hull is unique i.e. all of the different sets $x$ determines a unique center. However I'm not sure if this is true. Can you explain, please?

Comment: Ah good point, I was trying to keep it clean by not getting into the 2 vs 3 point thing, I guess I oversimplified.  I'll fix it up.

Comment: If two subsets of x have a circular hulls with different centers, then they are not both circular hulls of x.

Comment: Yeah, this is the most interesting detail. Can you explain why is it true that the center is unique? All of the other parts of the proof are OK.

Comment: The definition of circular hull is that it is minimum, which implies uniqueness.  I would make it a separate matter to prove that a minimum exists, or just assume it to avoid pedantry.

Comment: To be pedantic, in the $2$-point case $c$ isn't defined by just being equidistant, but being the unique minimizer of the greater of two distances.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks, fixed, the 2 vs 3 thing makes it so much less attractive.

Comment: "If that $y$ formed a circular hull of $x\cup\{p\}$ then it also forms a circular hull of $x$" why?

Comment: @alphacapture Damn.  When I go back and read this, I realize I can't even understand what I was trying to say.  So bad.  I need to refigure this out, or just let it's shame remind me to do a better job.